# Incredibly Simple Password System Not Working

Tags: javascript, passwords

So I've got this simple code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>SuM BUTtonsS DOe</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="buttons.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Please enter the password</p>
    <form id="enter" onSubmit="javascript:passCheck()">
        <input id="password" type="password" placeholder="Password">
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var input = document.getElementById('password');

        function passCheck() {
            if (input == 'herro') {
                window.alert("IT WORKS!!");
            }
            else {
                window.alert("darn");
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Shouldn't be too hard, right? The problem is it isn't working...

Everywhere I've checked seems to say the only thing you have to do is getElementById, and that'll give you the contents of the text field. However, I just keep getting the "darn" alert. Any ideas? I know the function is being called... Perhaps input must be in the function?

Comment: It is not acceptable to swear on SO. I've removed the swearing from your question.

Comment: `onXyz` attributes contain JavaScript code, not URLs. There's no need for the `javascript:` pseudo-protocol (the only reason it works is that it *just happens* to look like valid JavaScript syntax for a labelled statement).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try getting the value of the field, instead of the field itself:

```
 var input = document.getElementById('password').value;
```

Comment: Credit also goes to T.J. Crowder, because he told me to put the variable in the function.

Answer (score 1):

You are checking the DOM element against a string. The getElementById method returns a DOM element. What you want to do is check the element value against the string.
Changing the condition to

```
 input.value == 'herro'
```

should do the trick.

Comment: OP will also want to return false in the "it's not okay" case in order to prevent form submission, and remove the unnecessary `javascript:` prefix on the `onSubmit` attribute.

Comment: ... Huh? Could you post your answer in my HTML?

Comment: The HTML is too long to post here, just change this line:
 > if (input == 'herro')
to
 > if (input.value == 'herro')